# How to create a Docusign Custom Button on a Custom Object - Salesforce Lightning friendly

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

**What are the steps to create a "Send with Docusign" custom button for a custom Object in Salesforce.**

Considering:

1. Salesforce is migrating away from JavaScript buttons, and toward solutions that are mobile and Lightning-friendly;
2. "Send with DocuSign button" is only available on an Opportunities, Accounts, or Cases Objects to prepare an envelope;
3. Docusign for Salesforce documentation does NOT cover this topic.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The [Salesforce Developer recipes for DocuSign](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-salesforce-recipes-now-available/) may be of help.